# android tabhost how to launch new activity inside the tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have a Tabhost which is my main activity.
When a tab is clicked you will see the activity inside the Tabwidget.
In the inside activity i have this button which launch a new intent.
Is there a way that this intent can be launch in the same Tabhost and Tabhost widget? 
I want it to look the same and still to be with the Tabhost in the view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link out on TabGroupActivity and see how it works. This will display your tabs in whatever activity you launch.This should solve your problem.
http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-us-tab-group-activity-in-android.html